# Onchange function not working using laravel5

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5.1, onchange

My `onChange()` function is not working using Laravel 5 when I select the second category from same table. I can get the first category id. `onchange()` function is the problem. What do I need to change?

Controller

```
public function ajax_select_sub_second_cat(){
    $id =  $_GET['id'];
    $main_cat = Category_model::get_sub_category_ajax($id);
    //return view('siteadmin.add_cat',['main_cat' => $category]);
    if($main_cat){
        $return  = "";
        $return  = "<option value='0'> -- Select -- </option>";
        foreach($main_cat as $main_cat_ajax) {
            $return .= "<option value='".$main_cat_ajax->sub_category1."'> ".$main_cat_ajax->sub_category1." </option>";        
        }
        echo $return;
    } else {
        echo $return = "<option value='0'> --Select-- </option>";
    }
}
```

View

```
<select id="subcategory" name="product_sub_category" onChange="getCat1(this.value);"> 
    <option value="">-----Select Standard-----</option>
</select>
<script>
    function getCat1(id){
        var passData = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'get',
            data: passData,
            url: '<?php echo url('ajax_select_sub_second_cat'); ?>',
            success: function(responseText){  
                if(responseText){ 
                    $('#subcategory2').html(responseText);            
                }
            }   
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You mean the jquery on change ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need want to do some action in the change event of option select..

You can do like this

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    alert(optionSelected);
});
```

You can trigger any ajax call or anything that you wish to do here, and `optionSelected` is the item that is selected.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Cause of the Problem:

There is a syntax error in the value for `url` property of your 
AJAX request:

```
url: '<?php echo url('ajax_select_sub_second_cat'); ?>',
```

as the unconcatenated *single quotes* cause a syntax error.

The correct way would be:

```
url: "<?php echo url('ajax_select_sub_second_cat'); ?>",
```

Your code isn't badly written, and is possibly fair enough to solve the problem that you have at hand. Although, it could be made cleaner and better if you not mix up your JavaScript/jQuery code with PHP.

Do have a look at my suggestions below:

### PHP

First of all, since you have your `ajax_select_sub_second_cat` in a controller, and IF you haven't set up a route for it already, you can do so in `routes.php` as such:

```
Route::post('getSubCategories', 'theController@ajax_select_sub_second_cat');
```

You can access your posted data via any of the methods `GET` or `POST` if you inject/type-hint Laravel's `Illuminate\Http\Request` class into the method:

```
public function ajax_select_sub_second_cat(Request $request) // inject the HTTP request in the method
{
     //get the id of the selected field via post request
     $id = $request->input('id');

     //assuming that your Category_model returns the models
     $sub_cats = Category_model::get_sub_category_ajax($id);
     // ...
```

Next, instead of echoing out your data as `html`, you could echo it out as a JSON-encoded set/array of data:

```
     // ...
     echo json_encode($sub_cats->toArray());
 }
```

### jQuery

You can handle `change` events triggered by a DOM element with jQuery itself, although using `onchange` as an attribute of the element isn't an issue. To let jQuery handle this, use `change()` method:

```
$(function(){   
    $('#subcategory').change(function(){
        var selectedVal = $('#subcategory option:selected').text(); //this is how you get the selected value with jQuery
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ url('getSubCategories') }}",
            data: {
                id: selectedVal
            },
            dataType: 'json', // force the ajax request to return json data
            success: function(returnedData){
                 // ...
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now assuming you had echoed out an array of sub categories, iterate over the returned set of sub categories in the `success` handler of the AJAX request and populate the second select accordingly.

*Check out jQuery's [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for iteration on collections.*

Answer (score 0):

1- First of all you have to make sure that the event is fire on change and hit the url.

2- Check your console. You should use alert method for surety that the function run properly.

```
alert(id);
```

If alert is not showing on every change then check your dropdown code

```
<option value="id">Name</option>
```

All the dropdown value must be in this format.

3- After all replace

```
url: '<?php echo url('ajax_select_sub_second_cat'); ?>',
```

to

```
url: 'ajax_select_sub_second_cat',
```

Make sure the ajax_select_sub_second_cat is define in the route file other wise it will not work.

Hopefully you will not get any problem. You should use console when you make ajax request this will help a lot and save your time.